# LESS SCSS MIXIN conversion

Tags: css, sass, less

Body classes may have `.m01`, `.m02`, `.m03`, `.m04` depending on the colour break for the section of the pages.
I am trying to convert `LESS` into `SCSS`, but I am having trouble converting the mixing below.

```
//-LESS
//-Sample colours
@m01_col_lvl_01: red;
@m02_col_lvl_01: green; 
@m03_col_lvl_01: blue; 
@m04_col_lvl_01: black; 


//- start colour mixin loop
.module_colours(4);
.module_colours(@n, @i: 1) when (@i =< @n) {

//-colours
@col_lvl_01_multi: "m0@{i}_col_lvl_01";

.m0@{i} #site-name {
    background-color:@@col_lvl_01_multi;
}

//- end colour mixin loop
.module_colours(@n, (@i+1));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While  the answer provided by RaisingAgent is a reasonably good approach, it wouldn't teach you how to do this thing in Sass or help you understand how Sass works. This answer will help you with that.

Unlike Less, Sass does not allow you access a variable whose name is dynamically created through interpolation (the `@col_lvl_01_multi` variable). You will have to make use of lists and `nth` function for this.

Sass also has an in built `@for` directive which can be used to create loops and so there is no need to mimic the for loop using a mixin. So, your code can be converted to Sass as follows:

```css
$m_col_lvl_01_list: red green blue black; // the list

@for $i from 1 through 4 { // the loop
  .m0#{$i} #site-name { // interpolated selector name
    background-color: nth($m_col_lvl_01_list, $i); //nth function to access the value based on for loop index.
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Harry. I have a lot to learn  about SASS. I'm moving from LESS to SASS because Bootstrap is dropping support for LES in version 4. Now I have this comparison I can get stuck in.

Comment: Yup I was expecting that to be the reason and you're welcome. Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

On most Code snippet host sites you can 'Convert' / 'Compile' any kind of CSS code into normal `CSS(3)`. I always use [`Codepen`](http://codepen.io/pen/) and then a [`CSS to SCSS converter`](http://sebastianpontow.de/css2compass/). In your case, I'd just convert it in parts. (On Codepen, you have to click on the small **⚙** button and set your `CSS Preprocessor`).

Comment: I did not know that. Thanks RaisingAgent. I'll give it a whirl.