# Converting LESS "when" statements into SCSS conditional statements

Tags: sass, less, scss-mixins, metro-ui-css

To cite my sources, I'm converting the tiles functionality from [Metro-UI](https://metroui.org.ua/tiles.html) into a custom SCSS/Angular project I'm building. So far I've been able to convert much of it 1:1 by watching for mixins, includes, and variables. However, I'm not following what Metro's team is doing in this section when it comes to column arrangement. Their original code (from [their LESS file](https://github.com/olton/Metro-UI-CSS/blob/master/less/tiles.less) - line 243):

```
.tiles-grid {
    .create-tiles-cells(@i: 1, @k: 1) when (@k <= @i) {

        .tile-small.col-@{k} {
            grid-column: @k / span 1;
        }

        .tile-medium.col-@{k} {
            grid-column: @k / span 2;
        }

        .tile-wide.col-@{k} {
            grid-column: @k / span 4;
        }

        .tile-large.col-@{k} {
            grid-column: @k / span 4;
        }

        .tile-small.row-@{k} {
            grid-row: @k / span 1;
        }

        .tile-medium.row-@{k} {
            grid-row: @k / span 2;
        }

        .tile-wide.row-@{k} {
            grid-row: @k / span 4;
        }

        .tile-large.row-@{k} {
            grid-row: @k / span 4;
        }


        //.col-@{k} {
        //    grid-column: @k;
        //}
        //.row-@{k} {
        //    grid-row: @k;
        //}
        .create-tiles-cells(@i; @k + 1);
    }
    .create-tiles-cells(12);
}

.tiles-grid {
    &.size-half {
        width: 70px + @tileMargin * 2;
    }

    .create-tiles-grid-size(@i: 1, @k: 1) when (@k <= @i) {
        &.size-@{k} {
            width: (@tileCellSize + @tileMargin * 2) * @k;
        }

        .create-tiles-grid-size(@i; @k + 1);
    }
    .create-tiles-grid-size(10);
}

.tiles-grid {

    .generate-tiles-media-options(@mediaBreakpointListMobileLength);
    .generate-tiles-media-options(@name, @j: 1) when (@j <= @mediaBreakpointListMobileLength) {
        @m: extract(@mediaBreakpointListMobile, @j);

        @media screen and (min-width: @@m) {
            .create-tiles-cells(@i: 1, @k: 1) when (@k <= @i) {
                .col-@{m}-@{k} {
                    grid-column: @k;
                }
                .row-@{m}-@{k} {
                    grid-row: @k;
                }
                .create-tiles-cells(@i; @k + 1);
            }
            .create-tiles-cells(12);

            .create-tiles-grid-size(@i: 1, @k: 1) when (@k <= @i) {
                &.size-@{m}-half {
                    width: 70px + @tileMargin * 2;
                }
                &.size-@{m}-@{k} {
                    width: (@tileCellSize + @tileMargin * 2) * @k;
                }

                .create-tiles-grid-size(@i; @k + 1);
            }
            .create-tiles-grid-size(10);
        }

        .generate-tiles-media-options(@name, @j + 1);
    }
}
```

My conversion so far:

```
.tiles-grid {
    @mixin create-tiles-cells($i: 1, $k: 1) when ($k <= $i){

        .tile-small.col-#{$k} {
            grid-column: $k / span 1;
        }

        .tile-medium.col-#{$k} {
            grid-column: $k / span 2;
        }

        .tile-wide.col-#{$k} {
            grid-column: $k / span 4;
        }

        .tile-large.col-#{$k} {
            grid-column: $k / span 4;
        }

        .tile-small.row-#{$k} {
            grid-row: $k / span 1;
        }

        .tile-medium.row-#{$k} {
            grid-row: $k / span 2;
        }

        .tile-wide.row-#{$k} {
            grid-row: $k / span 4;
        }

        .tile-large.row-#{$k} {
            grid-row: $k / span 4;
        }


        //.col-${k} {
        //    grid-column: $k;
        //}
        //.row-${k} {
        //    grid-row: $k;
        //}
        @include create-tiles-cells($i, $k + 1);
    }
    @include create-tiles-cells(12);
}

.tiles-grid {
    &.size-half {
        width: 70px + $tileMargin * 2;
    }

    @mixin create-tiles-grid-size($i: 1, $k: 1) when ($k <= $i){
        &.size-#{$k} {
            width: ($tileCellSize + $tileMargin * 2) * $k;
        }

        @include create-tiles-grid-size($i, $k + 1);
    }
    @include create-tiles-grid-size(10);
}

.tiles-grid {

    @include generate-tiles-media-options($mediaBreakpointListMobileLength);
    @mixin generate-tiles-media-options($name, $j: 1) when ($j <= $mediaBreakpointListMobileLength){
        $m: extract($mediaBreakpointListMobile, $j);

        @media screen and (min-width: $m) {
            @mixin create-tiles-cells($i: 1, $k: 1) when ($k <= $i){
                .col-#{$m}-#{$k} {
                    grid-column: $k;
                }
                .row-#{$m}-#{$k} {
                    grid-row: $k;
                }
                @include create-tiles-cells($i, $k + 1);
            }
            @include create-tiles-cells(12);

            @mixin create-tiles-grid-size($i: 1, $k: 1) when ($k <= $i){
                &.size-#{$m}-half {
                    width: 70px + $tileMargin * 2;
                }
                &.size-#{$m}-#{$k} {
                    width: ($tileCellSize + $tileMargin * 2) * $k;
                }

                @include create-tiles-grid-size($i, $k + 1);
            }
            @include create-tiles-grid-size(10);
        }

        @include generate-tiles-media-options($name, $j + 1);
    }
}
```

It's of course the "when" statement that is causing the issue. I understand from similar questions that I may need to use a "for" or "each" statement and break it down from there, but the syntax rules are very different logic when I'm reviewing similar answers (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41587378/less-scss-mixin-conversion)). Since I didn't author the original LESS syntax I'm trying to work backwards through their logic to determine its SCSS equivalent.

From what I can tell it's trying to determine how to spread out the grids if/when the two values for I and K are different, but since you can't create a new class based upon a conditional variable in SCSS I'm getting tripped up. I'd appreciate any guidance. This is the last portion of my code that won't compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LESS and SCSS are a bit different when it comes to syntax – I always found SCSS to be the better choice – why my knowledge on LESS is somewhat limited.

I ran the LESS code on [codepen](https://codepen.io/jakob-e/pen/e851f8a56ce3b4edbec5821458cc26fe?editors=0101) and looked at the output – I think I'm able to help you with the first two parts. The last part with the media queries makes no sense it just produces a bunch of media queries and classes doing the same thing as the size part...
(let me know if you can produce something meaningful - then I'll have a second look).

I hope the comments makes sense :-)

Code on [sassmeister.com](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/dff9a86a71260f8364b25d3a731c866c)

```
// -------------------------------------------------------
//  Create tile cells mixin
//  if no arguments are passed 12 will be used as default
//  small note! mixins can't be nested in selectors
// -------------------------------------------------------
@mixin create-tiles-cells($count: 12){
  //  map holding size information (think object like)
  $sizes:(small: 1, medium: 2, wide: 3, large: 4);

  //  outer selector 
  .tiles-grid {
    //  loop from 1 through cell count
    @for $i from 1 through $count {
      //  loop through sizes map
      @each $key, $value in $sizes {
        //  print class using $key (small, medium,...)
        .tile-#{$key} {
          //  use & to bind the .col and .row class to the parent .tile-xxx  
          &.col-#{$i} { grid-column: $i / span $value; }
          &.row-#{$i} { grid-row:    $i / span $value; }
        }
      }
    }  
  }
}


// -------------------------------------------------------
//  Create tile sizes mixin
//  if no arguments are passed 10 will be used as default
// -------------------------------------------------------
@mixin create-tiles-grid-size($count: 10){
  //  variables 
  $tile-margin: 5px;
  $tile-cell-size: 150px;

  // @tileMargin: 5px;
  .tiles-grid {  
    //  hardcoded half class 
    &.size-half { width: 70px + $tile-margin * 2;}
    //  loop from 1 through size count
    @for $i from 1 through $count {
      &.size-#{$i}{ 
        width: ($tile-cell-size + $tile-margin * 2) * $i; 
      }
    }
  }
}


// -------------------------------------------------------
// Include the mixins 
// -------------------------------------------------------
@include create-tiles-cells(12);
@include create-tiles-grid-size(10);
```

Comment: Wow, I was hoping for guidance not practically full service! If I'm reading the for statement correct, what I need to understand about these things going forward is that it's setting up some sort of array to create classes on a counting system so that I don't have to declare "foo-1, foo-2, foo-3" but rather "for foo from 1 to X". Then I guess it applies a custom mixin based upon each of those. I think that makes more sense to me than the LESS markup now. Kudos to you!